# PHP calling a function before session destory or garabge collection

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

Im attempting to log the user activity in my database when they login and logout of the site. This works fine, but when they close the page via a tab or browser, there is no way to run the logout query, so according to the records the user never logs  out of the site.

**Method 1:** 
I have tried `onbeforeunload`, but this does not seem to trigger before the page closes.

**Method 2:**
I would try the method of using an ajax keepalive token sent to the php, but this would need to run every 1 min and could cause high traffic load.

**Method 3:**
I was hoping an alterantive would be to set the `session.gc.maxlifetime` to 1 min and add a call to the logout query via a destroy session callback.

Which would be the best method, or is there a better method of achieving this?

Is there a way to trigger a custom function(query) before php destroy session or php garbage collection has taken place?

**UPDATE**

I have taken the advise of everyone and decided to attempt 'method 1'. So far this is my attempt but its still not working perfectly:

```
    var isClosePage = true; 

    //detect f5 and backspace page navigation
    $(document).on('keypress', function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 116) 
        {
            alert('f5');
            isClosePage = false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 8) 
        {
            alert('backspace');
            isClosePage = false;
        }
    });

    //detect back and forward buttons
    $(window).bind('statechange',function()
    {
        alert('back');
        isClosePage = false;
    });

    //detect page button press
    $('html').on('mouseenter', function() 
    {
        console.log('mouse has enetered!');
        isClosePage = false;
    });

    //detect browser buttons press
    $('html').on('mouseleave', function() 
    {
        console.log('mouse has left!');
        isClosePage = true;
    });

     //make ajax call (logout) to server if above events not triggered
     $(window).on('beforeunload', function(e)
     {
        if(isClosePage)
        {
             $.ajax(
             {
                  url:'php/function/active-user.php?logout=ajax',
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  crossDomain: true, 
                  async: false
             });

             //return 'some default message';
        }
        else
        {
            isClosePage = true;
        }
    });
```

Can anyone suggest any improvments to how I can make this work well?

Answer (score 0):

When you speak of *Method 1*, you're doing it client-side, right?
The interface is `window.onbeforeunload`, and this is a usage example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  // call server script to log the user activity to database ...
};
```

The event `window.onbeforeunload` IS triggered before page is unloaded (tab/window/browser closed).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend MarcoS's answer a little bit. `window.onbeforeunload` should work but this isn't the preferred way to set a handler for events. Since this is a property other scripts attaching to this event will overwrite your listener and your function will never get called.

The preferred way of registering to this event is as follows:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (evt) {

}, false);
```

You could also attach a event listener to `unload`

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function (evt) {

}, false);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Orginally i had a jQuery alterantive, and this didnt work. I tried your first example and added an alert inside, but im getting the same results (page closes with no alert popup). This alert should popup before the page is closed via the browser tab yeah?

Comment: As far as i know it's not possible to call `alert()` when the page unloads. But it is possible to show a alert box by setting `event.returnValue` in your code. I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6kzwmov/1/). for you demonstrating this.

Comment: Yeah I have attempted many times to detect the page being closed using this unload and before unload(which is very hacky), the result with an ajax call doesnt allways work. Im needing to send a message to the server the user has closed the browser. Any suggestions on how do this?